# How would a person from the different eras in the past react to our society and technology?

Tags: time-travel

In Doctor Who and some other sci-fi stories (like the Navigator) we often see people from the past mostly from medieval times traveling to our time line.
So lets say we take people all the way back from the Stone age up until the late 1700 to early 1800, maybe with a 100 years in between them.
ala one from the 16th century one from the 17th etc etc.
And place them in our time long enough for them to get to learn about our society.
Also lets say we take one from each mayor civilisations over the the different eras.

How would each of them react to our world its technology, social rules and such.
Would it be like Hollywood often shows such things, of the savage barbarian thinking its all magic some god some bad or how would they view our world?

Comment: I would think that once you see that time-space insta-travel blue box that is larger on the inside than the outside, most other tech you see probably seems underwhelming at worst, or a given, at most.

Comment: Honestly, we can only speculate based on what we know of people's beliefs and society in any given era. Why do you think movies and books vary so much on how such characters respond to situations like this? They're guessing, filtering what they've heard about people of that time period through their own biases and beliefs, and their own sense of what makes for a good story, and using that to write a character. And since people are individuals, in reality every person would react a bit differently to being confronted by the future. So, as I said, we can only speculate.

Comment: Eric Flint and his collaborators wrote a very popular entertaining [series of many novels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1632_series) exploring how persons from the time of the Thirty Year's War would react to a modern-ish American town transported to their world. *Many* novels. Guess what? *Not all the people react in the same way.* Some adapt easily, some don't. Some appreciate modern culture, some don't. Some thrive in the changed conditions, some don't.

Answer (score 2):

**Language** would be a problem.
Even someone from 1800 USA would have difficulty understanding modern speech, as we have changed the meaning of words, invented new words, and stopped using worlds all over the place. *Simple* example: to this 1800's person the sentence "Check that gay bar" would be understood as "[chess move] that [happy, carefree] [wooden beam]"
...not very helpful.

Extreme **culture shock**. Admittedly some types can handle/ignore this much better than others, as even just traveling around the globe revealed just how strange humans can be.

**Diseases**.
We have bugs that would kill someone from the distant past very, very quickly. The lethality of this has been repeatedly demonstrated when previously uncontacted cultures were discovered. Mesoamerica: 90% deathrate to diseases brought from Europe!

**Communication** via technology.
We have gotten used to it, and it STILL tends to overwhelm us.
To anyone pre-1850, the sheer concept of having a live conversation with anyone outside of visible range is utter nonsense. The closest they had was written letters, or the *very* limited signalling between ships, etc.
The fact that we now have the ability, and use it all the time, and our very civilzation *depends* upon our ability, to communicate with anyone, anywhere with zero preparation (cellphones).
To disseminate news and entertainment globally, routinely, instantaneously (TV).
To watch *very* remote events as if we were present (more TV).
To access information stored so far away, we don't even have to know where it is, merely that it exists (Internet)!
All of these represent a level of communication that is utterly beyond what historical human ever experienced, or even conceived of experiencing.

Yes, most historical humans would consider a cellphone videocall to be sheer utter Magic. Doubly so if the other person is on a different continent.
This includes even someone from as recently as 1900

Comment: (1) The meaning "to control, to compare" of the verb "to check" is attested from the 17th century; the meaning "to examine" is from the late 1800s (originally, an Americanism). (And fewer people knew the specific chess meaning of "check" then than now; the primary meaning for a random person would have been "to stop, to restrain".) (2) They had "bars" in the 1800s sense of places where drinks are served. (The sense "counter over which drinks and food are served" dates from the 16th century.) (3) Whether the culture shock is "extreme" depends very much on the specific culture of the visitor.